# Count number of "active" for each date of a calendar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, count, between

I have 2 tables:

One is a temporary calendar table "Table1" with all dates between 2012-01-01 and today.

```
 Date
 ----------       
 2012-01-01
 2012-01-02
 .....
 2015-10-04
 2015-10-05
```

Second is "Table2" with a DateStart and a DateEnd.

```
 DateStart   |  DateEnd
 -------------------------
 2013-03-31  |  2013-04-30
 2013-02-01  |  2014-02-01
 2014-10-10  |  2015-01-10
 .....
 2015-03-06  |  2015-04-06
```

I would like to design a query that, for each date in the first table count the number of times this date is in between DateStart and DateEnd.

I would get something like:

```
 Date        |  Occurrence
 ------------|------------    
 2012-01-01  |     0
 2012-01-02  |     0
 .....       
 2013-04-29  |     2
 2013-04-30  |     2
 2013-05-01  |     1
 2013-05-02  |     1
 .....
 2015-04-05  |     1
 2015-04-06  |     1
 2015-04-07  |     0
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dt.date,COUNT(distinct bt.ID) 
FROM Dates_table dt 
LEFT JOIN batch_table bt ON dt.date between bt.start_date and bt.end_date
GROUP BY dt.date
```

Comment: Thank you Luc! I managed to adapt your solution to my problem and it seems to work.

Comment: Nice, you could post your solution for anyone else having this problem